# Function to convert all integer lists to floats for output

Tags: python, python-3.x, number-formatting

I've written this program that contains both string and integer info for participants in a Triathlon. There are some lists that contain the participants' track times in seconds. I need to somehow convert these times to minutes and output them as floats in 2 decimal points.

```
How many participants would you like to display?: 3

 Name: Jeff Adrian 
 Division: M4044
 Event: Standard Triathlon
 Gender: Male
 Swim: 2026 minutes 
 Transition 1: 329 minutes 
 Bike: 4625 minutes 
 Transition 2: 35 minutes 
 Run: 3847 minutes 
 Total: 10862.0
```

I'm not going to post the full lists for space reasons, but below you can find the loop I used to display the participants info and the function I'm currently stuck at:

```
for i in range(numToDisplay):
    ttl += float(swimTimes[i] + transition1Times[i] + cycleTimes[i] + transition2Times[i] + runTimes[i])

    print("\n Name: " + str(firstName[i]), str(lastName [i]), "\n", "Division: " + str(division[i]))

    if event[i] is 1:
        print(" Event: Standard Triathlon")
    else:
        print(" Event: Sprint Triathlon")

    if gender[i] is 1:
        print(" Gender: Male")
    else:
        print(" Gender: Female")

    print(" Swim: " + str(swimTimes[i]), "minutes", "\n", "Transition 1: " + str(transition1Times[i]), "minutes", "\n",
        "Bike: " + str(cycleTimes[i]), "minutes", "\n", "Transition 2: " + str(transition2Times[i]), "minutes", "\n", "Run: " + str(runTimes[i]), "minutes", "\n",
        "Total: " + str(ttl), "\n")
```

And the function to convert those track times to minutes:

```
def secToMin(s):
    s = 60
    minutes = list[i] / s
    float(minutes)
    return minutes
```

I can gladly provide more info on the program if needed.

Comment: Please format your code correctly.

Comment: try something like this.  print("%.2f mins" % (seconds / 60.0))

Comment: Its not clear to me what's going on. Much of the code seems irrelevant to the question. What's that being passed to `secToMin`? Seconds? In python 3, all you have to do is `s/60` and you've got a float of minutes. If you have, say, `70` seconds, did you want `1.16` minutes (round down), `1.17` (round up) or a traditional `1:10` (minutes:seconds)?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need a function like this:

```
def secToMin(seconds):
   _seconds = seconds
   #I wasn't sure if you were storing as string or integer
   if type(_seconds) is str:
       _seconds = int(_seconds)
   secondsRemaining = _seconds%60
   minutes = _seconds/60
   return "%0.02d minute(s), %0.02d second(s)" %(minutes,secondsRemaining)
```

Then, if you have an array of times, you can convert them all one shot and store them into a separate array using the 'map' function:

```
timesArray = [1000,1500,500,"1400","900"]
newArray = map(secToMin,timesArray)
```

Or if you have a bunch of participants, you can loop through them and generate it one by one:

```
Alice = ["Alice",1400]
Bob = ["Bob", 1300]

participants = [Alice, Bob]

for participant  in participants:
    print secToMin(participant[1])
```

**Note:** The function returns a string above since you deal with strings when you are concerned with formatting things like number of decimal places. You could easily return floats as well, if you need them for later by returning an array instead (but you'll need to simply account for this when you're handling the returned output from the function):

```
def secToMin(seconds):
    _seconds = seconds
    if type(_seconds) is str:
        _seconds = int(_seconds)
    secondsRemaining = _seconds%60
    minutes = _seconds/60
    return ["%0.02d minute(s), %0.02d second(s)" %(minutes,secondsRemaining),float(minutes),float(secondsRemaining)]
```

Hope this is what you were looking for!

Comment: Your first function is using the float conversion specifier (`f`) to convert integers --- `%0.02f` should be `%02d` for both minutes and seconds.  Your second function is returning a list that contains a string and two floats --- it should probably return a tuple of two floats (which can be unpacked easily: `min, sec = secToMin(whatever)`).

Comment: Thanks, Kevin. Good catch about %f (that was a typo). And you're right about the tuple unpacking, but I was writing it in case OP was keen about getting the function to about a string directly. Great suggestion, though!